# Cisco DHCP using dynamic updates

Tags: cisco-ios, dhcp, dns

I would like to use a configuration on a Cisco router that allows for clients to resolve the names of other clients without the use of mDNS. I have following configuration:

```
roTST01#show running-config | section dhcp
ip dhcp pool DSL
 network 10.0.220.0 255.255.255.0
 update dns both
 default-router 10.0.220.1 
 dns-server 10.0.220.1 

roTST01#show running-config interface gigabitEthernet 0/0
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address 10.0.220.1 255.255.255.0
end
```

I have two clients that are utilizing IPs from the DHCP server:

```
roTST01#show ip dhcp binding 
Bindings from all pools not associated with VRF:
IP address      Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type       State      Interface
                Hardware address/
                User name
10.0.220.4      0152.5400.19f6.49       Jun 09 2021 01:38 PM    Automatic  Active     GigabitEthernet1
10.0.220.6      0152.5400.0cdb.74       Jun 09 2021 01:54 PM    Automatic  Active     GigabitEthernet1
```

But the hostnames of the devices (Client01 & Client02) are not added to the DNS zone in order for the clients to resolve them.

```
Client02#ping client01
Translating "client01"...domain server (10.0.220.1)
% Unrecognized host or address, or protocol not running
```

I added a manual entry, just to test if resolution in general works, and it does:

```
roTST01#show hosts 
Default domain is testnet.local
Name servers are 10.0.220.1
NAME  TTL  CLASS   TYPE      DATA/ADDRESS
-----------------------------------------
 91.222.16.172.in-addr.arpa     10      IN      PTR     proxy
 proxy  10      IN      A       172.16.222.91
```

So from my understanding, as soon as a client got a DHCP lease, there should be a new entry in this list looking something like this:

```
roTST01#show hosts 
Default domain is testnet.local
Name servers are 10.0.220.1
NAME  TTL  CLASS   TYPE      DATA/ADDRESS
-----------------------------------------
 4.220.0.10.in-addr.arpa     10      IN      PTR     Client01
 Client01  10      IN      A       10.0.220.4
```

What am i missing?
Edit: Special announcement for Ron Maupin, here is the DNS configuration of the device:

```
roTST01#show running-config | section dns
ip dns server
```

Comment: Where is your configuration of the router as a DNS server?

Comment: You're missing the fact that the DNS server in IOS is beyond primitive. It does not support dynamic updates, and the internal DHCP engine does not update the "static" hosts list.

Comment: @Ricky: Thanks for your answer. So as i understand it, the DHCP server can update any external DNS servers that may support dynamic updates but not the internal one. So sad to see that every $50 hobby router can do this but the almighty cisco cannot...

Comment: I added the DNS configuration, please reopen the question so Ricky can post his answer. I want other people that have the same question in the future be able to come to this conclusion by googling.

Comment: There is more to configuring the IOS DNS server. At the very least, you need to configure the domain name and set your device as the primary DNS server for the domain. As Ricky pointed out, you want to use real DHCP and DNS servers for your business.